# how to set exact same date with momentjs in any environment?

Tags: javascript, express, momentjs

I'm trying to set a date to a particular timezone with the following function:

```
const setDate = moment("2022-04-03T19:23:00").tz(ENV.TZ,true);
```

It's working well on my local however it is Not working once deployed, apparently I'm setting 1 day less for some reason.
e.g.:
in my local environment:

console.log(setDate); // Moment<2022-04-03T19:23:00+02:00>

somewhere in the cloud:

console.log(setDate); // Moment<2022-04-02T19:23:00+02:00>

any idea how to set a consistent timezone no matter what environment the code is running in?

Comment: `moment.tz("2022-04-03T19:23:00", ENV.TZ)`. The problem is you're parsing the date string as a local time then setting the timezone. Using this parses the date in the provided timezone

Comment: Worked well in local, however issue persists once deployed, it return a day ahead (for some reason), using AWS.